# when appending a item getting string indices must be integers error-python

Tags: python, append, payload

I am a very beginner and struggling with a POST Request. I would like to have a conditional variable in payload

```
import json
adults=int(input(Enter no.of adults:)
childs=int(input(Enter no.of childs:)
payload = json.dumps({"dates": {"from": "check_in_date","to": 
"check_out_date"},"propertyId":"%hotel_code","leadGuest": {"birthDate": "1991-09- 
13","contact": {"address": "Address","city": "City","country": "Country","email": 
"Email_Address","phone": "MobileNo","state": "State","zip": "Zipcode"},"name": {"first": 
"First_Name","last": "Last_Name"},"title": "MR"},"reference": {"agency": 
"JhdGVQbGFuQ29kZSI6Ik1212"},"paymentDetails": {"type": "credit_card","details": {"number": 
"4111111111111111","cvv": "123","expiry": {"month": "01","year": "2028"},"name": {"first": 
"First_Name","last": "Last_Name"}}},"rooms": [{"roomCode": "roomCode","roomId": 
"roomId","rateCode": "rateCode","ratePlanId": "ratePlanId","expectedPrice": {"amount": 
"amount","currency": "USD"},"guests": [{"birthDate": "1992-09-13","contact": {"address": 
"Address","city": "City","country": "Country","email": "%Email_Address","phone": 
"MobileNo","state": "State","zip": "Zipcode"},"name": {"first": "First_Name","last": 
"Last_Name"},"title": "MR"}]}],"meta": []})
 print(payload[0]) #output is {
 print(payload["guests"] #output is string indices must be integers
 if adults == 2:
    payload['guests'].append({"birthDate": "1980-09-13","name": {"first": 
"Adultguest","last": "test"},"title": "MR"})
if childs == 1:
    payload['guests'].append({"birthDate": "2018-09-13","name": {"first": 
"childguest","last": "test"},"title": "MR"})
```

This code report error "string indices must be integers"
How can i solve this

Comment: Take a look at: [Getting started](https://www.python.org/about/gettingstarted/), [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your code isn't runnable due to syntax errors

Comment: Why are you using `json.dumps`, what is it you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json.dumps() function converts a Python object into a json string. It returns a python string representing the json string. You cannot access it like json.
You could assign your data in as a dictionary like this

```
 payload = {"dates": {"dates": {"from": "check_in_date","to":

           .....

            }
```

and for json

```
payload_json = json.dumps(payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps() turns a dictionary into a string, this is why payload[0] outputs "{", because it is indexing the first character in the string, so when you do payload["guests"] you are indexing a string with a string